# List all Organizational Units (OU) and Sub OU's in aspx page

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a question that I have been searching for the answer for but can't seam to find one that works. I have an ASP.Net web application that I need to list all sub OU's of a specific OU. Does anyone now how would be best to go about this?

For example I want to list all the OU's under `Users` and then enable the user to click on that OU and then see a list of user contained within that OU. I am able to list users within OU's already but I am currently unable to list the Sub OU's.

Here is the code that I have already;

```
DirectoryEntry Ldap = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ou=Users;ou=ASH;ou=Establishments;dc=domain;dc=com", aduser, adpass);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Ldap);
//specify that you search user only by filtering AD objects
searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=user)";

try
{
   foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
   {
      //loop through each object and display the data in a table
      DirectoryEntry DirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

      TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
      TableCell tblcell_Username = new TableCell();
      TableCell tblcell_displayName = new TableCell();
      tblcell_Username.Text = DirEntry.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
      tblcell_displayName.Text = "";
      tblRow.Controls.Add(tblcell_Username);
      tblRow.Controls.Add(tblcell_displayName);
      ADWeb_Tbl.Rows.Add(tblRow);

      //DEBUG LINES
      //On peut maintenant afficher les informations désirées
      //Response.Write("Login: " + DirEntry.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value);
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Response.Write(ex.Source + "<br />");
   Response.Write(ex.Message + "<br />");
   Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you for taking the time to read this question.

Comment: So what happens when you run your code?

Answer (score 1):

Two main points:

1. if you want to find the organizational units - why are you searching for users?!?!? This makes no sense at all. Use this code:

   ```
   DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Ldap);
   // specify that you search for organizational units 
   searcher.Filter = "(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)";
   searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.SubTree;  // search entire subtree from here on down
   ```
2. when you get the results from the searcher, you should try to avoid calling `.GetDirectoryEntry()` on each single one of them. Specify which attributes you need in the `DirectorySearcher` - and then use those attributes directly on the search results:

   ```
   searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");  // and add any others you need

   try
   {
      foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
      {
         TableRow tblRow = new TableRow();
         TableCell tblcell_Username = new TableCell();
         tblcell_Username.Text = result.Properties["SAMAccountName"].ToString();
   ```

Comment: The code I posted was just an example of what I am currently using to get a list of users from AD. I didn't think SMSAccountName applied to OU's? Also when I run this code I get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Any ideas?